# How to refer to custom Vertexes to add an Edge, using JGraphT

Tags: java, jgrapht

I have a graph `SimpleWeightedGraph<Vertex, DefaultWeightedEdge> g` where Vertex is a custom class. I have all the vertexes and the edges in a postgresql spatial db.
I need to load only a subset of them, to find a path from two vertexes, so I use some queries.

The Vertex class has a `String` as identifier and other parameters that I load from the db. I need them later.

I first load all the needed vertexes with some queries. In a second time I add the edges (with other queries) but I need to refer to the vertexes that are already in the graph.

Now the question: **how can I make this?**

Here are some extracts of my code.

*The Vertex class:*
(I want the Vertex are equals if they have the same id, and they are ordered with the same natural order of the Strings, by their id. I want it's also possible do `vertex.equals("something")`)

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>{
    private String id;      //identifier
    private double x;       //x in SRID 900913
    private double y;       //y in SRID 900913
    private String geom;    //geome in EWKT
    private int a;
    private int p;

    public Vertex(String id, double x, double y){
        [...constructor body...]
    }
    public Vertex(String id, Vertex v){
        [...constructor body...]
    }
    public Vertex(String id, double x, double y, int a, int p){
        [...constructor body...]
    }
    public Vertice(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
            boolean result;

            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (obj.getClass() != String.class)
            {
                if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
                    return false;
                }
                Vertex v = (Vertex) obj;
                result = this.id.equals(v.getId()); 
            }
            else
            {
                String s = (String) obj;
                result = this.id.equals(s);
            }

            return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        final int prime = 31;

        int result = 1;

        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex v){
        return this.id.compareTo(v.getId());
    }

    [...other methods...]
}
```

*Extract of another part of the code, where I create the vertexes of the graph:*

```
query = "select id_v, x, y from [table_name] where [conditions]";

rs = st.executeQuery(query);

while (rs.next())
{
    v = new Vertex("w"+rs.getInt("id_v"), rs.getDouble("x"), rs.getDouble("y"), start.getA(), 0);
    //start is a Vertex
    g.addVertex(v);
}

[...other parts of code like this one, but with different query...]
```

*Now I need to create the edge.* Here is the code:

```
query = "select v1, v2, weight from [table_name] where [conditions]";

rs = st.executeQuery(query);

DefaultWeightedEdge e;
String v1;
String v2;

while (rs.next())
{
    v1 = "w"+rs.getInt(1);    //source_vertex_of_edge.equals(v1) is true
    v2 = "w"+rs.getInt(2);    //target_vertex_of_edge.equals(v2) is true
    weight = rs.getDouble(3);

    //the next line doesen't work because addEdge wants (Vertex, Vertex) as parameter
    e = g.addEdge(v1, v2);

    g.setEdgeWeight(e, weight);
}
```

I also tried:

```
query = "select v1, v2, weight from [table_name] where [conditions]";

rs = st.executeQuery(query);

DefaultWeightedEdge e;
Vertex v1;
Vertex v2;

while (rs.next())
{
    v1 = new Vertex("w"+rs.getInt(1));    //source_vertex_of_edge.equals(v1) is true
    v2 = new Vertex("w"+rs.getInt(2));    //target_vertex_of_edge.equals(v2) is true
    weight = rs.getDouble(3);

    e = g.addEdge(v1, v2);

    g.setEdgeWeight(e, weight);
}
```

But this doesen't work: when I add the edge, the source and target vertexes (already being in the graph) lose all parameters except id.

How can I refer to them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph does not explicitly know anything about the `id` that you are storing in the vertex. Particularly, it does not know that this is the "key" by which a `Vertex` object should be identified later. There is no way of "extracting" an existing vertex from the graph when only the `id` of the vertex is known (except for iterating and checking each vertex - which is not feasible even for relatively small graphs)

A very simple and pragmatic solution would here be to store all vertices in a map. This way, you can just look up the matching vertex for a given ID string.

Sketched here, roughly based on your code:

```
class TheClassThatLoadsTheGraph
{
    private final Map<String, Vertex> idToVertex =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Vertex>();

    void readVertices()
    {
        ...
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String id = "w"+rs.getInt("id_v");
            Vertex v = new Vertex(
                id, rs.getDouble("x"), rs.getDouble("y"), start.getA(), 0);
            g.addVertex(v);

            // Store the vertex in the map:
            idToVertex.put(id, v);
        }
    }

    void readEdges()
    {
        ...
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String id1 = "w"+rs.getInt(1);
            String id1 = "w"+rs.getInt(2); 
            double weight = rs.getDouble(3);

            // Use the ids to look up the matching vertices
            Vertex v1 = idToVertex.get(id1);
            Vertex v2 = idToVertex.get(id2);
            DefaultWeightedEdge e = g.addEdge(v1, v2);

            g.setEdgeWeight(e, weight);
        }
    } 
}
```

---

### NOTE:

You mentioned that you wanted a special behavior for the `equals` method:

> I want it's also possible do vertex.equals("something"))

This is **not** possible without severely breaking the contract of the `equals` method. If you could do this, you also would have to make sure that

```
"something".equals(vertex);
```

but this is obviously not the case. Equality is a very strong concept, and the details of *properly* implementing the `equals` method can be tricky. Whatever you intended to achieve there: **Try to find a different approach for that**! (Maybe the `idToVertex` map from the above code snippet may be helpful here as well...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's what I'm looking for. I also modified the equals method. Now `vertex.equals("something")` is no longer available and return false: with the `Map` I no longer need it.